# VBA Shell command have Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: shell, vba, cmd

I get an error #5:

```
"Invalid Procedure Call or Argument"
```

When I run the following command:

```
Dim i as Integer
i = Shell(" copy /y C:\directory\from\file.dbf C:\directory\to\file.dbf ", vbMaximizedFocus)
```

Any help?

Comment: Why not `FileCopy "C:\directory\from\file.dbf", "C:\directory\to\file.dbf"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `copy` executable. The command is built into `cmd.exe`. Also, there must not be any whitespace at the beginning of your command. Change the instruction to this:

```
i = Shell("cmd /c copy /y C:\src\file.dbf C:\dst\file.dbf", vbMaximizedFocus)
```

Note that you'll have to quote paths containing spaces.